# auto complete on asp.net control

Tags: c#, asp.net

hey I want to use autocomplete jquery in asp.net on a control which is used on a default1.aspx page. My control is searchinput.ascx which is in Registration folder. My ploblem is I have written web method (getmylist) on code file of searchinput control. but that method is never called. can anyone help me

Comment: Do you have these data-annotations? `[WebMethod]` and `[ScriptMethod]`

Comment: is your prob solved with our answers then don't forgot to accept the right answer..

Answer (score 0):

[Jquery website](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

You can find wat you need there for a start.
Also, show your ajax call so that I can try helping on y it is not working.
Your approach of writting a web method and making a ajax call from the jquery auto complete should work out fine otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to help you without the code but some common causes could be:

- You are not using ClientID value correctly - asp.net controls dont have the same id in the actual mark-up as they do in the designer
- your web method has an error in it - you should press f12 to open your web developers toolbar and go to NET tab (in firefox at least) to see if a 500 error code or similar is being returned

Answer (score 0):

Create a web method like the following:

```
 [WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string[] GetPatientFirstName(string prefix)
{
    List<string> customers = new List<string>();
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
    {
        string connectionstring = CCMMUtility.GetCacheForWholeApplication();
        conn.ConnectionString = connectionstring;
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "select distinct top(10) PatientFirstname from tblMessage where  " +
            "PatientFirstname  like '%'+ @SearchText + '%' order by PatientFirstname";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", prefix);
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    customers.Add(string.Format("{0}", sdr["PatientFirstname"]));
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
        return customers.ToArray();
    }
}
```

here is the html code :

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $('[ID$=txtPatientFirstname]').live('keyup.autocomplete', function () {

            $(this).autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Resources/WebService.asmx/GetPatientFirstName") %>',
                        data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    label: item.split('-')[0],
                                    val: item.split('-')[1]
                                }
                            }))
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        },
                        failure: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        }
                    });
                },
                select: function (e, i) {
                },
                minLength: 1
            });
        });
});
```

This is the working example ......hope this will solve your problem..